# Angular ui-router runs controller twice on load if it is specified in the $stateProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am seeing that code in my controller is being ran twice , thus showing in the console.log windows output in chrome dev tools

**questions.html**

```
<div ng-controller="questionController as vm"> </div>
```

**questionController.js**

```
var questionController = function($location, questionService, $env) {
    var vm = this;
    console.log('in the controller')  // this runs twice 
}
```

**app.js**

```
app.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    '$locationProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

        var viewBase = '/apps/src/views/';

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

        $locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); // get rid of ! was getting #! 

        $stateProvider
            .state('questions',
            {
                url: "/questions",
                templateUrl: viewBase + "questions.html"//,
                //controller: "questionController"
                //views: {
                //
                //}
            });


    }]
);
```

Notice that I commented out the `controller: "questionController"` in the route,  otherwise it ran twice.

I know that I used ui-router last year and i always used controller: without any problems.

Perhaps some new version combinations causing a bug?

**Based on an answer i was trying but not data not displaying**

I am using `ui-grid`

```
 <!--<div ng-controller="questionController as vm">-->

       <div ui-grid="{ data: vm }" class="grid"></div>

  <!--</div>-->
```

Notice i commented out div with the ng-controller

```
  var vm = this
  var promise = questionService.getAllQuestions();

    promise.then(function(response) {
        vm.myData = response;
        console.log('questionCtrl promise data', vm.myData);
    });
```

The console.log does work to spit out data

**Fixed**

Seems that I had to do

route

```
     controller: "questionController",
     controllerAs : "vm"
```

OR

```
      controller: "questionController"
```

Then

```
 <div ui-grid="{ data: vm.myData }" class="grid"></div>
```

Comment: This is the expected behavior. You should not define the controller in the view, just in the stateprovider. By this design you can easy reuse the template for different controllers

Comment: here the problem is you are initializing controller in `template` and the `state` definition. remove `ng-controller` form `questions.html` and mention that in state definition alone. if you want to use `vm` use `controllerAs` in state definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are including the controller in your `$stateProvider` as well as the template itself by doing

```
<div ng-controller="questionController as vm"></div>
```

You can remove `ng-controller` from your HTML

Comment: Well, now my data from a service will not display     `promise.then(function(response) {
            vm.myData = response;`